# "Circular dependency" error when running cronjob from CLI using n98-magerun

Tags: magento-2.1, cron, cli

I'm running my cronjob using n98-magerun (for testing purposes):

```bash
./n98-magerun2.phar sys:cron:run my_cron_job
```

However, the job is not running, and the following error occurs:

> [LogicException]
>
> Circular dependency: Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session depends on Magento\Backend\Model\Authorization\RoleLocator and vice versa.

I've flushed caches & var/generation, so it's not that. Has anyone come across this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was using an old version of n98-magerun. Updating to the latest version fixed this issue:

```bash
./n98-magerun2.phar self-update
```